# Jersey web.xml application issues

Tags: java, xml, jersey

Whenever I run my test app on Tomcat I can make it to my main page but whenever I try to go to my api/rest path I received a 500 error because my AppConfig could not be found. I believe this has to do with my directory set up.

My xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>FACHybrid</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>java.config.ApplicationConfig</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

In the xml the issues lies with the param-value tag

Here is the ApplicationConfig file

```
package config;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

import service.TestService;

@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application{

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> s = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        s.add(TestService.class);
        return s;
    }

}
```

and my directories look like this

[image]

error in console

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.config.ApplicationConfig
```

Comment: `java` is not part of the package name. It is simply a directory where all your Java files go.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in your `web.xml`. Fully qualified name of `ApplicationConfig` class is wrong.

Change it to `config.ApplicationConfig` -

```
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>config.ApplicationConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
```